# How to see newer commit after checkout into an old commit

Tags: git

I want to know how one can see the newer commit after checkout to some older one. Through eclipse git plug-in I find no problem. But through command when i tried 'git whatchanged' It just gave me all the previous commits from the current checkout. I am not able to look at the newer commit. Can anyone tell me what is the command for getting all the commits even when we checkout to some older commits...

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --all
```

will show you all references.

```
git log HEAD@{1}
```

Will show you everything from what you had checked out 1 checkout ago (see reflog)

```
git log some-branch-name
```

will show you every commit starting at a particular branch tip's commit.

These parameters work just the same for `gitk`.

Comment: read about the DAG (directed acyclic graph) to see how git traverses history. This will all make sense then.